# Error - pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to the opportunity....Except it's not

Tags: apex, unit-test

As you can see i insert a pricebook assign that pricebook to the opportunity, assign the pricebook entry to that pricebook and assigned the entry to the opportunity line item.

So opportunitylineitem.PricebookEntryId.pricebook2Id should be equal to opportunity.pricebook2Id...But it says it's not. What am i missing?

edit: added system.debug to check the pricebook. They match, this should work and it should insert. There's no pricebook assignment in any other apex class that i've been able to find.

Test class

```
            PriceBook2 priceBook = TestDataUtility_SalesToolkit.stPriceBook2(true, null);
          insert priceBook;
    
        PricebookEntry standardPbe = TestDataUtility_SalesToolkit.stPriceBookEntry(true, new Map<string, string> {
          'Pricebook2Id' => Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
          'Product2Id' => prod2.Id
        });
        insert standardPbe;
    
        PricebookEntry pbe = TestDataUtility_SalesToolkit.stPriceBookEntry(true, new Map<string, string> {
          'Pricebook2Id' => priceBook.Id,
          'Product2Id' => prod2.Id
        });
        insert pbe;
    
        Opportunity opp = TestDataUtility_SalesToolkit.stOpportunity(true, new Map<string, string> {
          'Pricebook2Id' => priceBook.Id
        });
          insert opp;
    
        OpportunityLineItem opli = TestDataUtility_SalesToolkit.stOpportunityLineItem(true,new Map<string, string> {
          'OpportunityId' => opp.Id,
          'PricebookEntryId' => pbe.Id
      });
  system.debug(' opp pricebook ' + opp.Pricebook2Id);
  system.debug(' pbe pricebook ' + pbe.Pricebook2Id);
  system.debug(' actual pricebook id '+ priceBook.Id);//These all match
          insert opli;  <---fails here
```

Test data utility

```
    @istest
public with sharing class TestDataUtility_SalesToolkit {
   

    /**
    * This is dummy method; class marked as test class must have at least one test method
    * 
    */
    @isTest
    static void dummyTest()
{
    Test.startTest();
    
    System.assert(true, 'Should be always OK');
    
    Test.stopTest();
}

   /**
    * Creates Account object
    *
    * @param  useDefaults True to use default data hardcoded in test
    * @param  data        Map with data provided by user
    * @return             New object instance
    */
    public static Account stAccount(Boolean useDefaults, Map<String, Object> data)
{
    return (Account) putValues(
        new Account(),
        new Map<String, Object>{
            'Name'                     => 'test_Account',
            'RecordTypeId'             => Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Customer').getRecordTypeId(),
            'CurrencyIsoCode'          => 'USD'
                },
        useDefaults,
        data
    );
}


    /**
    * Creates Opportunity object
    *
    * @param  useDefaults True to use default data hardcoded in test
    * @param  data        Map with data provided by user
    * @return             New object instance
    */
    public static Opportunity stOpportunity(Boolean useDefaults, Map<String, Object> data)
{
    return (Opportunity) putValues(
        new Opportunity(),
        new Map<String, Object>{
            'Name'                     => 'test_opp',
            'RecordTypeId'             => Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Machines').getRecordTypeId(),
            'CloseDate'                => date.today(),
            'StageName'                => 'Identified'
                },
        useDefaults,
        data
    );
}

    /**
    * Creates product2 object
    *
    * @param  useDefaults True to use default data hardcoded in test
    * @param  data        Map with data provided by user
    * @return             New object instance
    */
    public static Product2 stProduct2(Boolean useDefaults, Map<String, Object> data)
{
    return (Product2) putValues(
        new Product2(),
        new Map<String, Object>{
            'Name'                     => 'test_product2'
                },
        useDefaults,
        data
    );
}

   /**
    * Creates OpportunityLineItem object
    *
    * @param  useDefaults True to use default data hardcoded in test
    * @param  data        Map with data provided by user
    * @return             New object instance
    */
    public static OpportunityLineItem stOpportunityLineItem(Boolean useDefaults, Map<String, Object> data)
{
    return (OpportunityLineItem) putValues(
        new OpportunityLineItem(),
        new Map<String, Object>{
            'Quantity'                 =>  1
                },
        useDefaults,
        data
    );
}



/**
    * Creates PriceBook2 object
    *
    * @param  useDefaults True to use default data hardcoded in test
    * @param  data        Map with data provided by user
    * @return             New object instance
    */
    public static PriceBook2 stPriceBook2(Boolean useDefaults, Map<String, Object> data)
{
    return (PriceBook2) putValues(
        new PriceBook2(),
        new Map<String, Object>{
            'Name'                     => 'North America Price Book',
            'IsActive'                 => true
                },
        useDefaults,
        data
    );
}

    /**
    * Creates priceBookEntry object, needs product2Id
    *
    * @param  useDefaults True to use default data hardcoded in test
    * @param  data        Map with data provided by user
    * @return             New object instance
    */
    public static priceBookEntry stPriceBookEntry(Boolean useDefaults, Map<String, Object> data)
{
    return (priceBookEntry) putValues(
        new priceBookEntry(),
        new Map<String, Object>{
            'UnitPrice'                => 10,
            'IsActive'                 => true
                },
        useDefaults,
        data
    );
}




     /**
     * Method sets defaults (if requested) and user provided values on given sObject
     *
     * @param  obj         sObject to populate with data
     * @param  defaults    Map with default values
     * @param  useDefaults If the map with default values should be used
     * @param  data        Map with user provided values
     * @return             sObject with data
     */
    private static sObject putValues(sObject obj, Map<String, Object> defaults, Boolean useDefaults, Map<String, Object> data)
    {
        // result map that will be applied to object
        Map<String, Object> finalValues = new Map<String, Object>();
        
        // if defaults should be used and are available then apply them to the result
        if (useDefaults && defaults != null) {
            finalValues.putAll(defaults);
        }
        
        // if data are present then apply then to result map
        if (data != null) {
            finalValues.putAll(data);
        }

        // apply all items from the map to given object
          for (String fieldName : finalValues.keySet()) {
           obj.put(fieldName, finalValues.get(fieldName));
                }
        
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Comment: requery the `opp` after insert to verify that the `opp.pricebook2Id` hasn't changed through some other automation

Answer (score 0):

There was something in process builder assigning it.